# The message "[ProcessSuspension] 0x282ead7c0-processassertion () Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 0"

Tags: ios

When WKWebVeiw runs an HTML page, this message appears in Xcode's console:

> [ProcessSuspension] 0x282ead7c0-processassertion () Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 0

Then, an HTML page that has been visited before is automatically loaded.

Could you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Have you ever find out how to solve this?

Comment: any solution for this?